# iPhone/iPad/iPod turn-off blocking?

Tags: iphone, ios, power, find-my-iphone

Its possible to block turning off the iPhone/iPod or iPhone?
For example, in case of loss, theft? 
The point is that the thief could not turn off the iPhone, so I could find iPhone through Find my iPhone always..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can't prevent someone turning the phone off.

If it's jailbroken, you can install [Powerguard](http://modmyi.com/content/8025-powerguard-keeps-people-using-your-power-off-slider.html) or [NoPowerDown](http://modmyi.com/content/7770-review-nopowerdown-disable-ios-power-down-interface.html).

Answer (score 1):

No.

Even devices locked with TouchID can be turned off without unlocking. Even if you could restrict it, the device would eventually run the battery dead.